# Convert only one page to https in django

Tags: django

Using this [https](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure) i can convert my entire project to https.

But i just want to convert only one page to https. All other pages should be in http.

Exapmle i have the following URLs

```
url(r'^related-product/$', related_product),
url(r'^payment-status/$', paymentStatus),
url(r'^get-kitchenstyle-images/$', singleKitchenStylesImages),
url(r'^makepayment/$', makepayment),
url(r'^add-accessory-to-session/$', add_accessory_to_session),
```

I have to call only makepayment in https. All other url as http

Is this possible ?
If possible how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your apache configuration file.
Your specific url is  makepayment

```
RewriteEngine On
# enable the Rewrite

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?makepayment/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/makepayment/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could force ssl by:

- a proxy
- the server
- django middleware

As you only want one url to be rewritten the quick fix solution would be to add a rewrite rule, which depends on your server setup. Are you using nginx? lighttpd? apache?

You can also find a few [middleware snippets on google](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/) that are easy to adjust to check for a specific url.